# Alternator connection is bad

Tags: honda, alternator, accord, wiring, battery-cable

So I have a problem where one of the wires connecting to the alternator comes loose and stops charging my battery. I have an 08 Honda Accord. I have pulled the wire out and attempted to clean the connection ports since there is a lot of dirt buildup in it, and when I do my battery light on my dashboard will turn off once the wire and my battery are reconnected and the car starts up , but one bump in the road and the light is back on, it also goes away sometimes if I put downward pressure on the connector. I truly don’t know what’s going on I know my alternator and battery are okay since when the car is running and the wire is connected properly my car voltage is about 14.1 volts but when it’s disconnected my voltage drops down to 12.56 as if the alternator is not charging the battery at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which connector are you talking about? Connection at the battery? The clipped connector (which may have more than one wire in a plastic holder)? The large red wire which goes from the battery to a post on the back of the alternator? A picture showing what you're talking about may help us tremendously in understanding what's going on so we can helpfully help you :o)

Comment: Please take a photo or two of the wire you are talking about and update your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either your alternator terminal, or the lug on the wire which attaches to your alternator, is physically corroded.

Been there done that - rust will not conduct electricity no matter how many times you try.

It sounds like the plating has corroded off either the lug or the terminal.  It will need to be replaced, unless you like wire-brushing it down once a week.   To replace the wire lug, crimp on an automotive-grade crimp of good quality.

To replace the terminal stud on the alternator, are you sitting down?  It's usually attached to the rectifier, so the alt would have to be torn apart to reach it, and it unsoldered from the windings. While you have the alternator is in pieces, also replace the brushes, commutator and bearings since these are wearing items.

Hmm, might be easier just to replace the alternator with a rebuilt one.